# Unable to use inheritence in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Please have a look at the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.att_marks.students.Attendance_Btech">
  <id name="id" type="integer" column="id" >
   <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>

  <property name="year">
     <column name="Year" />
  </property>
  <property name="semister">
    <column name="Semister"/>
  </property>
  <property name="section">
    <column name="Section"/>
  </property>
  <property name="period">
    <column name="Period"/>
  </property>
  <property name="subjectCode">
    <column name="Subject_Code"/>
  </property>
  <property name="date">
    <column name="Date"/>
  </property>
  <property name="status">
    <column name="Status"/>
  </property>
  <union-subclass name="com.att_marks.students.Attendance_Btech_ECE" table="attendance_btech_ece">

  </union-subclass>
 </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I have tables named attendance_btech_ece, attendance_btech_cse, attendance_btech_it, and so on. All these tables use the same schema as mentioned above for the Attendance_Btech class. I thought this should work but it isn't.

Comment: Are you getting an error message or stack trace?

Comment: null pointer exception at a statement like this: session.createQuery(query); but the thing is i haven't tried to use this class object till this point of execution but it still throws an exception, if i remove this file from configuration file then everything is working fine...

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace? It might not have anything to do with the mapping (That's usually figured out upon startup).

Comment: the exception is raising at a point where this particular class is not used at all, when this hbm file is removed out of configuration file, it is working fine..... it just says java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

If the `Attendance_Btech_ECE` is subclass of `Attendance_Btech` then should work.

Comment: YOu can optionaly add extends="Attendance_Btech"